# Can we implement inheritence in C

Tags: c, inheritance

I have seen that we can implement multiple inheritance in ANSI C? 
As we can create any class like

```
struct sampleClass {
    int size;
    struct sampleClass *ptr1;
};
```

As I tred to create class and want to implement inheritance. Can you give me some idea how to implement that?

Comment: Are you asking about [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3322650/2065121)?

Comment: Of course it's possible to implement multiple inheritance in C. In fact, the very first C++ compiler created C code that was compiled by a normal C compiler. It's not that simple though.

Comment: C structs are not "classes" in the OOP sense. They are just collections of data fields, OOP "classes" should also have methods and support inheritance. You *can* implement just about anything in C including any OOP mechanism, but you have to do it yourself, in code, compiler will not do it for you, so result is going to be verbose and messy.

Comment: @XORcist C with classes and this and that and other fancy stuff, that would be C++. But both are considered different languages.

Comment: Perhaps you should ought to start out with single inheritance? In event here is a pretty good write-up with a few implementation options and considerations: http://lwn.net/Articles/444910

Comment: So, please clarify. Do you have an actual *specific task* to implement inheritance mechanism in C, on top of structs? If not, then switch language... A short list of languages, which have "real classes" but otherwise very C-like syntax and structure: C++, Objective-C, D, C#, Java

Comment: Regarding classes: object orientation doesn't concern itself with the implementation details of a class, as long as it has private encapsulation and possibility of inheritance. Other things such as constructors, destructors, this-pointers etc are convenient, but they are not related to OO design as such. A struct can have private encapsulation through incomplete/opaque type. Incomplete type can also be used for inheritance, as can struct pointers and function pointers. So you can do object-oriented programming in C, but you cannot have classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this being done before.

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define FRUIT_COLOR_RED   1

struct fruit {
    char* name;
};

struct apple {
    struct fruit base;
    int color;
};

void printFruit(struct fruit *f) {
    printf(f->name);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct apple a;
    a.base.name = "apple";
    a.color = FRUIT_COLOR_RED;

    printFruit((struct fruit*)&a);

    return 0;
}
```

This works because struct fruit is the first member of struct apple and the two structures are aligned in memory.

|-- 4 or 8 bytes(char*) --| => struct fruit in memory

|-- 4 or 8 bytes(char*) --|-- 4 or 8 bytes(int) --| => struct apple in memory

The first 4 or 8 bytes(depending on 32 bit vs 64 bit respectively) are the same length and type so you can cast a struct apple* to a struct fruit* and because they line up in memory, it reads the members of struct fruit.

I don't know if this is good practice and I would avoid it. I love the simplicity of C, but why not use a language that has these constructs built in such as C++.

Too implement Object Orientation features in C is going to mean more lines of code and more maintenance.

Also if the code doesn't build I wrote it now in notepad, but the concept is there. Don't have a C compiler on me at the moment :-(.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "implementing [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in C".

It has certainly been done with macros, coding guidelines and styles, and `struct` of function pointers (mimicking [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)) and other [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata).  A good example comes from [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) with its [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) layer.